# Error when set auto increment in prodceduce

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE client_logging_system.Proc_client_Delete(IN in_clientID int)
  COMMENT '
-- Parameter:
-- in_clientID: ID of client
'
BEGIN
  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  end;
  
  START TRANSACTION;
  
  DELETE FROM `client` WHERE `client`.ID = in_clientID;
  ALTER TABLE `client` AUTO_INCREMENT = in_clientID;
  
  COMMIT;
END
```

My proceduce get error on line:

```
ALTER TABLE `client` AUTO_INCREMENT = in_clientID;
```

Any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Any suggestion for this problem? - use dynamic sql.. But code does not make sense, add sample data and expected outcome as text to help clarify.

Comment: If you're hoping to make sure id values are consecutive, then stop. Don't do that.

Comment: Even if the alter table worked, it would end your transaction, since DDL can't be in a transaction in mysql

Comment: Please do explain *why" you want to do this; this is almost certainly not the right approach for your underlying goal

Comment: When we set a field to primary and auto-increment constrant, if we delete record, the value in that field will continue auto sign base on the greatest number when insert new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables in `ALTER` statements, it needs a literal number there. You'll need to create dynamic SQL using [`PREPARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

```
SET @st = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `client` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', in_clientID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @st;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use limited set of DDL statements inside a routine.

What are you trying to achive with the ALTER TABLE-statement? If you delete a client with id that is not the biggest one, the ALTER TABLE would not make sense.